# MySQL - two columns with same kind of data

Tags: mysql, select, join, rows

My question is this: I have a table which has two columns and the primary key is composed by these two columns. The first columns has the name id1 and the second is id2.
Considering that I have a certaing row (10,15), I want to get rid of the rows (15,10) because I want to create a table with unique combinations of id1, id2.
How can I do this is MySQL? I tried several conditions with SELECT, JOINS, etc.

Thanks for the patience.

Just clarifying a little bit more:

Suppose I have this table:

Table(id1, id2) with the rows: (10,15), (10,12), (12,16), (15,10), (12,10), (13,14)

I want to end up with something like this:
(10,15), (10, 12), (12, 16), (13,14)

Basically, if I have two values id1 and id2, there must be only one row that have them in any order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
insert into newtable
select distinct least(id1, id2), greatest(id1, id2) from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I entirely understand your question, but have you tried:

```
    Delete from table where id1=15 and id2=10;
```

?

Or are you trying to formulate a way to prevent these kind of rows from being created to begin with?

Comment: The thing is, I have a table with multiple entries and it has rows with id1, id2 and id2, id1. I want to select only the rows id1, id2...